# Pressing <press Alt-3> suddenly maps to Esc (and not the character "#"

Tags: vim, keyboard, mapping, keyboard-shortcuts

Pressing  suddenly seems to map to the command `Esc` (and not the character "#", How do I access the map.

I tried the following command:

```
:unmap <Alt-3>
:unmap <Alt-3> Esc
:unmap <press Alt-3>
:unmap <press Alt-3> Esc
```

I want be able to write the character "#" with the shortcut <kbd>Alt-3</kbd>

Comment: Are you using a GUI Vim or a terminal Vim, and if the latter, what terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: thanks for you comment @bk2204. I have a Terminal Vim. I use `iTerm` on MacOS. But now that you mention it, the problem doesn seem to appear on the "standard" terminal: in only appears on `iTerm`. Do you have any idea about how the fix the problm on `iTerm`?

Comment: Go to: Preferences > Profiles > Keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in your iTerm configuration, which was set to send `ESC+3` when `<Alt-3>` was pressed.

You can solve the problem be going to iTerm2 menu `Preferences > Profiles > Keys` and setting `Left Option (alt) Key` there, changing from "Esc+" to "Normal".